# Is $c_0$ a Banach space for a non-standard norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is well known that the space $c_0$, consisting of all real sequences converging to zero, equipped with the supremum norm
$$
\|(x_n)\| = \sup_n |x_n|
$$
is a Banach space.

> Does there exists a norm $\| \cdot \|_1$ which is not equivalent to the norm defined above and such that $c_0$ equipped with this norm is still a Banach space?

Comment: If you forget the given norm, then $c_0$ is just a vector space of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$ which admits all sorts of complete norms.  Maybe you want a norm that is "natural" in some way?

Comment: @EricWofsey Nice, I completely forgot about that. However, I have two questions: (1) why $2^{\aleph_0}$ and not $\mathfrak c$? (2) How can I generate "all sorts of complete norms"? Is there a standard procedure? And how can I check that these norms are not necessarily equivalent to the standard norm?